# Find two real numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $a<q<b$ and $b-a<1$

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Let $q$ be a natural number. Find two real numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $$a<q<b$$ and $$b-a<1$$

Can we deduce something about the **nature** of $a$ and $b$ such as rationals or irrationals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply define $a = q - \frac{1}{4}$ and $b = q + \frac{1}{4}$.
In this case $a,b$ are both rationals.

However, one can also define $a = q - \frac{1}{\pi}$ and $b = q + \frac{1}{\pi}$. In this second case $a,b$ are both irrational.

So we cannot deduce nothing about rationality of $a,b$.

Answer (score 1):

Not at all.

For example, take $q=9$. Then you can take any $a\in(8.5,9)$ and $b\in(9,9.5)$, and in these intervals there are infinitely many of rational and irrational numbers.